# select user icon on click

Tags: jquery

I am creating a user registration form, and there is an option to select avatar icon for user and for that I am using following code...

```
 <ul class="icons clearfix">
     <li><img src="images/123456.jpg" title="123456" alt="123456" width="34" height="34" /></li>
     <li><img src="images/654321.jpg" title="654321" alt="654321" width="34" height="34" /></li>
 </ul>
```

and following jquery code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.icons li').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var selected_img = $('img',this).attr('alt');
        $('.avatar').val(selected_img); 
    });

});
```

First of all, is my approach correct? And it should remove selected class from `li` element if user clicks again on any other image and avatar image should be updated accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually use the IMG for the click, not the LI.

```
 $('ul.icons img').click(function() {
        $('ul.icons img').removeClass('selected'); // -- remove all other SELECTED
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var selected_img = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('.avatar').val(selected_img); 
    });
```

Comment: but can you please tell me, why did we use img instead of li?

Comment: It makes semantic sense. The user is selecting the image, so why select the item wrapping it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on extra js, I like to use what's already built-in using radio buttons and labels:

```
<ul class="icons clearfix">
    <li>
        <input type='radio' id='icon-123456' value='123456' name='current_icon'/>
        <label for='icon-123456'>
            <img src="images/123456.jpg" title="123456" alt="123456" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' id='icon-654321' value='654321' name='current_icon'/>
        <label for='icon-654321'>
            <img src="images/654321.jpg" title="654321" alt="654321" width="34" height="34" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then just hide the radio buttons:

```
.icons input{
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('ul.icons li').click(function() {
    $('ul.icons li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, yours way is even great, i would try it as well. thanks alot.